# Finding resource in entire deployment project

Tags: java, maven

I've got main project "A" consists of sub-project "B" with configurations and resources.
Project "A" has got dependencies to external module "C" responsible for exact functionality.

In "C" I need to scan entire deployment classpath and fetch resources from this sub-project "B". (in runtime)

Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: if you need a resource located in src/main/resources/some/file.ext use this.getClassLoader().getResource("some/file.ext")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent project in maven is just an aggregator `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. It does not create a jar.

With subproject you mean propably a mavem multimodule project with two modules A,B.
Project A has main method. Project B is used as dependency in A. 
Also C is dependency in A.

I tried this: 
In project C I created class which is scanning all resources. I'm calling this class from main method from A. It shows also resources in B module.

It works when running it from IDE.

Comment: Certainly, but I thought that there is any possibility to scan in runtime entire classpath - it would enable to find resource in module B without any dependency to this project